# PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. | GCloud Analytics API | Ubuntu | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am working with Google Analytics API. **My code is working locally**. But it is not working on the Ubuntu Server instance. I have checked and done the following steps correctly:

1. ADC is signed in using `gcloud auth login`. I received a token and browser and signed in successfully.
2. The key file is accessible. I have tried `console.log(keyFileData)` and it is coming correct.
3. The service account is configured successfully.
4. Analytics Access has been given view access to the Service account email.

```
--- Client library initialization ---

  private readonly analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
```

```
--- My configuration in my NestJS service File constructor ---
const keyFileContents = fs.readFileSync('./g4-client.json', 'utf8');

    try {
      const keyFileData = JSON.parse(keyFileContents);

      // Create a Google Auth client using the key data
      const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        credentials: keyFileData, // Pass the entire key object
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
      });

      // Create a Google Analytics Reporting API client
      this.analytics = google.analyticsreporting({
        version: 'v4',
        auth: auth,
      });

      // Use the 'analytics' client for API requests
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing JSON key file:', error);
    }
```

```
--- My code where I am trying to call the API ----
try {
      const [response] = await this.analyticsDataClient.runReport({
        property: `properties/12345678`,
        dateRanges: [
          {
            // Cast the DateRange object to `any` to allow the interval property to be set.
            startDate: '30daysAgo',
            endDate: 'today',
          },
          {
            startDate: '7daysAgo',
            endDate: 'today',
          }
        ],
        dimensions: [
          {
            name: 'city',
          },
        ],
        metrics: [
          {
            name: 'activeUsers',
          },
        ],
        limit: '7',
        orderBys: [
          {
            desc: true,
            metric: {
              metricName: 'activeUsers',

            },
          }
        ],
        dimensionFilter: {
          filter: {
            fieldName: 'pagePath',
            stringFilter: {
              matchType: 'EXACT',
              value: productHandle
            }
          }
        },
      });

      const weeklyData = [];
      const monthlyData = [];

      response.rows.forEach((row) => {
        const dimensionValues = row.dimensionValues;
        const metricValue = row.metricValues[0].value;

        // Determine if it's weekly or monthly data based on dimensionValues[1].value
        const dateRange = dimensionValues[1].value;

        // Create an object to store the data
        const dataItem = {
          city: dimensionValues[0].value,
          metricValue: metricValue,
        };

        // console.log(dimensionValues, metricValue, dateRange, dataItem);
        // Push the data into the respective arrays
        if (dateRange === 'date_range_0') {
          monthlyData.push(dataItem);
        } else if (dateRange === 'date_range_1') {
          weeklyData.push(dataItem);
        }
      });

      return { weeklyData, monthlyData }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error running the report:', error);
    }
```

[image: My gcloud config list]

```
--- Error being encountered -----------
Error running the report: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
4|api.xxx.com  |     at callErrorFromStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:82:17)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:360:55)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:458:34)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:419:48)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:132:24
4|api.xxx.com  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
4|api.xxx.com  | for call at
4|api.xxx.com  |     at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:325:42)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@google-analytics/data/build/src/v1beta/beta_analytics_data_client.js:190:29
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
4|api.xxx.com  |     at OngoingCallPromise.call (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at NormalApiCaller.call (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:84:30
4|api.xxx.com  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
4|api.xxx.com  |   code: 7,
4|api.xxx.com  |   details: 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes.',
4|api.xxx.com  |   metadata: Metadata {
4|api.xxx.com  |     internalRepr: Map(4) {
4|api.xxx.com  |       'endpoint-load-metrics-bin' => [Array],
4|api.xxx.com  |       'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array],
4|api.xxx.com  |       'google.rpc.errorinfo-bin' => [Array],
4|api.xxx.com  |       'grpc-status-details-bin' => [Array]
4|api.xxx.com  |     },
4|api.xxx.com  |     options: {}
4|api.xxx.com  |   },
4|api.xxx.com  |   statusDetails: [
4|api.xxx.com  |     ErrorInfo {
4|api.xxx.com  |       metadata: [Object],
4|api.xxx.com  |       reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
4|api.xxx.com  |       domain: 'googleapis.com'
4|api.xxx.com  |     }
4|api.xxx.com  |   ],
4|api.xxx.com  |   reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
4|api.xxx.com  |   domain: 'googleapis.com',
4|api.xxx.com  |   errorInfoMetadata: {
4|api.xxx.com  |     service: 'analyticsdata.googleapis.com',
4|api.xxx.com  |     method: 'google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport'
4|api.xxx.com  |   }
4|api.xxx.com  | }
4|api.xxx.com  | undefined
4|api.xxx.com  | Error fetching city-wise data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'weeklyData')
4|api.xxx.com  |     at AnalyticsResolver.fetchCityWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/src/analytics/analytics.resolver.ts:42:35)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at target (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator.js:74:28)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.fetchCityWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-proxy.js:9:24)
4|api.xxx.com  | [Nest] 20957  - 10/12/2023, 8:48:08 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Error fetching city-wise data
4|api.xxx.com  | Error: Error fetching city-wise data
4|api.xxx.com  |     at AnalyticsResolver.fetchCityWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/src/analytics/analytics.resolver.ts:47:13)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at target (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator.js:74:28)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.fetchCityWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-proxy.js:9:24)
4|api.xxx.com  | Error running the report: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
4|api.xxx.com  |     at callErrorFromStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:82:17)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:360:55)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:458:34)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:419:48)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:132:24
4|api.xxx.com  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
4|api.xxx.com  | for call at
4|api.xxx.com  |     at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:325:42)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@google-analytics/data/build/src/v1beta/beta_analytics_data_client.js:190:29
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
4|api.xxx.com  |     at OngoingCallPromise.call (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at NormalApiCaller.call (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at /var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:84:30
4|api.xxx.com  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
4|api.xxx.com  |   code: 7,
4|api.xxx.com  |   details: 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes.',
4|api.xxx.com  |   metadata: Metadata {
4|api.xxx.com  |     internalRepr: Map(4) {
4|api.xxx.com  |       'endpoint-load-metrics-bin' => [Array],
4|api.xxx.com  |       'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array],
4|api.xxx.com  |       'google.rpc.errorinfo-bin' => [Array],
4|api.xxx.com  |       'grpc-status-details-bin' => [Array]
4|api.xxx.com  |     },
4|api.xxx.com  |     options: {}
4|api.xxx.com  |   },
4|api.xxx.com  |   statusDetails: [
4|api.xxx.com  |     ErrorInfo {
4|api.xxx.com  |       metadata: [Object],
4|api.xxx.com  |       reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
4|api.xxx.com  |       domain: 'googleapis.com'
4|api.xxx.com  |     }
4|api.xxx.com  |   ],
4|api.xxx.com  |   reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
4|api.xxx.com  |   domain: 'googleapis.com',
4|api.xxx.com  |   errorInfoMetadata: {
4|api.xxx.com  |     service: 'analyticsdata.googleapis.com',
4|api.xxx.com  |     method: 'google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport'
4|api.xxx.com  |   }
4|api.xxx.com  | }
4|api.xxx.com  | Error fetching city-wise data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'weeklyData')
4|api.xxx.com  |     at AnalyticsResolver.fetchCountryWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/src/analytics/analytics.resolver.ts:59:35)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at target (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator.js:74:28)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.fetchCountryWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-proxy.js:9:24)
4|api.xxx.com  | [Nest] 20957  - 10/12/2023, 8:48:08 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Error fetching city-wise data
4|api.xxx.com  | Error: Error fetching city-wise data
4|api.xxx.com  |     at AnalyticsResolver.fetchCountryWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/src/analytics/analytics.resolver.ts:64:13)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at target (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator.js:74:28)
4|api.xxx.com  |     at Object.fetchCountryWiseData (/var/www/api.xxx.com/node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/external-proxy.js:9:24)
```

I don't know what to do. What details should I check?

Comment: 1. make sure that its actually loading the key file data.   2.  try passing a path to the key file instead of a data dump which i assume is what keyfiledata means.   you may want to just set the env var its probably easier.  Can i assume this is a service account your using right?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, Ok.  Yes, I am using a service account. Can you help me with that? I believe this is incorrect: ```credentials: '/root/g4-client.json', ``` How can I pass the complete file in credentials or any other way which I can use.

Comment: Also, one more thing. I have pasted the initialization of the client library. Please check. I think it is using ADC rather than the key file initialization in the constructor.

Comment: the error message is strange to me.   it looks fine.  I think you not accessing the key file.  readFileSync('./g4-client.json', 'utf8');    check that you have access to it and can open it